# How can I get a finer grained span in my MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'm using an MKMapView and I'm initializing like this:

```
homeLocation.latitude = 42.033126;
homeLocation.longitude = -70.168621;

[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:homeLocation animated:NO];

MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion;

viewRegion.center = homeLocation;
viewRegion.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1.7, 1.7);

[self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion] animated:NO];
```

and here is my app

[image]

That's fine, except for my app I need to have it zoomed out a tiny bit more. But when I try this:

```
viewRegion.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1.8, 1.8);   // use span of 1.8, not 1.7
```

I get this:

[image]

It is zoomed way out. If I look at the MKMapView's region the latitudeDelta i 3.54981 and the longitudeDelta is 3.51562.

How can I set my span to a value between 1.7 and 3.5? I'd love to hit around 2.25 for this particular application.

NOTE: the mapview pinch zooms just fine to whatever span I want.

Answer (score 1):

MKCoordinateSpanMake uses degrees, and 1 degree is about 69 miles. If you want a more fine grained setting, use MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance instead.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D homeLocation;
homeLocation.latitude = 42.033126;
homeLocation.longitude = -70.168621;

[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:homeLocation animated:NO];

 MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance( homeLocation, 200000, 200000);
// 200000 meter is approximately 1.8 degree
[self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion] animated:NO];
```

Comment: the map region still resizes quantumly, not smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried on the device? Sometimes I have more control on the zoom level on the device than on the simulator.

Comment: oh yes, sorry I was clearer in my post. When you pinch to zoom in or out, it works fine. I just can't initialize the mapview to a span I want.

Comment: Yes. I was not talking about the pinch to zoom but about setting the region. I have an animation where I set the region many times per second - a customized zoom in with a slight curve - and on the simulator it only changes the zoom once in every 50 updates or so but on the device it always updates the zoom.

Comment: oh! I see what you mean, yes, I'll check that out tomorrow. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: No, testing on a real device doesn't help.