# mkmapview setRegion behaves strange when zoom region is small

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview

I have one simple MKCircle overlay on map. Clicking buttom zooms to circle Coordinate:

```
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(3.970639, 12.238926), 100, 100);
[self.mapView viewRegion animated:YES];
```

I don't know why, but even though I always "zoom" to exactly same region (I even hardcoded it), the zoom works only when there is huge difference between current and wished zoom. Example is displayed in GIF.

Any idea why is this happening or how to always zoom map to the same level?

GitHub:
[Github](https://github.com/knagode/MapProblemProject/)

Main file:
[ViewController.m](https://github.com/knagode/MapProblemProject/blob/master/MapProblemProject/ViewController.m)

[image]

Comment: It may not be possible, I encountered a similar situation awhile back. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760390/how-can-i-get-a-finer-grained-span-in-my-mkmapview

Comment: @PaulCezanne: did you find solution for the problem? To me - it seems like Apple bug ..

Comment: No, I did not and yes, I agree with you!