# How to open Apple Maps with a location and zoom?

Tags: ios, ios8

The following code will open Apple maps (iOS8) at the correct location "mapLocation", but the option MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey seems to be ignored. The map view is always about 250m across on a portrait iPhone, regardless of the settings in span. The values for MKCoordinateSpan span latitude/longitudeDelta I've tested are in the range 0.3-2 degrees. How do I get the zoom level I want?

```
        MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:mapLocation addressDictionary:nil];
        MKMapItem *item = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
        item.name = pointID;
        options = @{MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey:[NSValue valueWithMKCoordinateSpan:span],
                    MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:MKMapTypeHybrid]};

        [item openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:options];
```

Comment: It does work. (1) Do not supply a center; the MKMapItem includes the placemark, that's all you need. (2) prove that your `span` is a valid value, please.

Comment: For e.g. span = (MKCoordinateSpan) $0 = (latitudeDelta = 2.0775132286066551, longitudeDelta = 1.6175174895337534). These are supposed to be the map width and height in degrees, right?  mapLocation = (latitude = -43.036322506617658, longitude = 171.64364905480267). MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey gets set correctly. map shows on correct centre, but the width is about 250m. iPhone 5s & iOS 8.1.2

Comment: Hmmm, I see what you mean. Are you trying it on the simulator or on a device. If simulator, try device and see if it's any better...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760390/how-can-i-get-a-finer-grained-span-in-my-mkmapview - Basically you can't get fine grain without it, which stinks.

Comment: @matt, yes a real device.

Comment: @PaulCezanne, hmm. Not so much not fine grained, as no grain at all. I get the same view (maybe 0.002 degrees wide) in Apple maps no matter what values I set for the span. Looking like a bug in the API? Also, note that the question is about using the Apple maps app, not an MKMapView.

Comment: I agree, I think this is a bug. I thought it _was_ working, though; I'll check later...

Comment: Didn't work any better in iOS 7 simulator.